# Hibernate timeout when saving

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an app that uses MySql to save into a table (This table has 2 JSON fields and one of the can receive a large input). Every now and then in production I'm having the getting the following error:

> SqlExceptionHelper - The last packet successfully received from the server was 71,290,382 milliseconds ago.
>   The last packet sent successfully to the server was 71,290,384 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server 
>   configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity 
>   before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J 
>   connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

I'm not understanding why this happens, since localy I never faced this issue. This is the configuration I currently have:

```
cfg.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "5")
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "20")
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "30000")
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "50")
                .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "3000")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.autoReconnect", "true")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.autoReconnectForPools", "true");
```

Am I missing something?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue a while back. I was searching in the history and while you can keep the values that you have, you would need to add this one: `<property name="connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</property>`. That did the trick for our artifact, but you would need to check in your case since you may have some other settings.

As a side note, I believe it should be:

```
.setProperty("connection.autoReconnect", "true")
.setProperty("connection.autoReconnectForPools", "true");
```

---

We also had a `c3p0.properties` file:

```
c3p0.preferredTestQuery=select 1 from dual
c3p0.maxConnectionAge=3600
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin=false
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
c3p0.acquireRetryDelay=1500
c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts=15
c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure=false
c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod=200
```

Pay attention to [testConnectionOnCheckout](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#testConnectionOnCheckout) in particular.